# How to do this integral

Tags: integration

Is there a straighforward way to evaluate the following
\begin{equation}
\int\frac{e^{e^{2i \theta}}e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}+2}\,d\theta
\end{equation}
I tried the expansion but stucked here
\begin{equation}
\int\frac{e^{2\cos\theta}[\cos(2\sin\theta)+i\sin(2\sin\theta)][\cos\theta+i\sin\theta]}{\cos\theta+2+i\sin\theta}\,d\theta
\end{equation}

Comment: Indefinite integral or definite? If definite, what are the integral limits?

Comment: With $z = e^{i\theta}$, the integrand becomes (up to constants) $\frac{e^{z^2}}{z+2}$. If you're integrating around the whole unit circle, then this isn't bad at all. If you're hoping for an antiderivative...I'm pessimistic.

Comment: it is an indefinite integral, or it will be zero for definite integral on whole unit circle.
I tried to the step of $\int e^{2x}\log(x+2)dx$, which is still difficult to go further.

Comment: I agree with John ... no straightforward way for the indefinite integral, but easy to do around a closed curve using residues: depends on the winding number around $-2$.

Comment: I guess the answer to the question you asked -- "Is there a straightforward way..." --- appears to be "no." But one-word answers aren't allowed. :(